# Facebook does not obay the Google Play's central opt out of the Ad ID

Tags: facebook

**Moved to: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4962/facebook-does-not-obay-the-google-plays-central-opt-out-of-the-ad-id**

Facebook states in this [Terms and services](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a17) that it respects Google plays advertising id:

> Yes, the Audience Network SDK for Android uses the Advertising ID and respects its limit tracking option in accordance with Google Play's terms and conditions.

I checked it by sniffing its traffic, and it is true. But it is striking that it does not obay google plays opt-out mechanism:

[image]

I still could see that it used the IDFA Header even after opting out.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/network_ads_common/
MAKE:               LGE
IDFA_FLAG:          1
APPVERS:            1.1.10
ATTRIBUTION_ID:     
NUM_ADS_REQUESTED:  1
CARRIER:            
SDK:                android
SCREEN_HEIGHT:      592
VIEWABLE:           1
ADAPTERS:           AN
REQUEST_TYPE:       0
SDK_CAPABILITY:     [3,4,5,7,11]
CLIENT_EVENTS:      
COPPA:              false
PLACEMENT_ID:       ????
SDK_VERSION:        4.7.0
TEMPLATE_ID:        200
OS:                 Android
BUNDLE:             ???
DENSITY:            2.0
APPNAME:            ???
OSVERS:             4.4
SCREEN_WIDTH:       384
SCHEMA:             json
PLACEMENT_TYPE:     native
APPBUILD:           10
LOCALE:             en_GB
MODEL:              Nexus 4
IDFA:               a6a1bca3-1f90-408e-8a9b-960ba26aa60a
```

So is that behavior legal from facebook and can I do something about that?

**Edit**
It seems that they need to obay the opt out mechanism:

> Usage. The Android advertising identifier must only be used for advertising and user analytics. The status of the “Opt-out of Interest-based Advertising” setting must be verified on each access of the ID.

From:  [Google Play Developer Programme Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

Comment: 'access' is different from use isn't it? I'm wondering whether their initial reading and caching of the ID is 'access' and then it is used again and again from cache/in-app memory and this isn't covered?

Comment: I actually reseted facebooks and my app cache and app data and it still used my tracking id, but it is correct observation.

Comment: Legal questions aren't I am scope for this site.

Comment: @NeilSmithline maybe you are right, which stack exchange site would be better. I just thought taht it would be very nice to document this behavior somewhere where people can actually find it when they need it.

Comment: Legal.SE seems right to me